# For a custom Am335 board, how to write minimum device tree ? what should be included?

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot, device-tree

I have a custom board, which has AM335. I want to boot from the network or from SD card. what component should be there in Device tree?  I would say the just minimum.

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit/include from `am33xx.dtsi` and `am335x-bone-common.dtsi` you should be able to boot from network (TFTP/NFS) on your AM335 board.

```
/dts-v1/;

#include "am33xx.dtsi"
#include "am335x-bone-common.dtsi"

/ {
    model = "TI AM335x BeagleBone Black";
    compatible = "ti,am335x-bone-black", "ti,am335x-bone", "ti,am33xx";
};

&ldo3_reg {
    regulator-min-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-max-microvolt = <1800000>;
    regulator-always-on;
};

&mmc1 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
};

&mmc2 {
    vmmc-supply = <&vmmcsd_fixed>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&emmc_pins>;
    bus-width = <8>;
    status = "okay";
};

&lcdc {
    status = "okay";
};
```